# Playing Audio of Decoded RTP packets

Tags: c#, audio, byte, wav, rtp

I captured RTP packets and Decoded them with this code:

```
public byte[] Decode(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream src=new MemoryStream(data);
    System.IO.BinaryReader brsrc=new BinaryReader(src);
    MemoryStream dst=new MemoryStream();
    System.IO.BinaryWriter bwdst=new BinaryWriter(dst);
    int step=(int)(data.Length/10);
    for(int i=0;i<step;i++)
    {
        byte[] d=new byte[160];
        va_g729a_decoder(brsrc.ReadBytes(10),d,0);
        bwdst.Write(d);
    }
    byte[] ret=dst.GetBuffer();
    brsrc.Close();
    bwdst.Close();
    src.Close();
    dst.Close();
    return ret;         
}
```

using the g729 dll.

now I have a byte array full of Decoded RTP packets, How do I play it or turn it into a WAV file or something close?

Thnaks,
Ofek

Comment: Is that not what the decode method gives you?

Comment: I decoded the rtp packets and now I have them ready to be played. I want to know how to turn them into a WAV file or any audio file that can be played (after I decoded them)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ffmpeg** to convert the rtp data to voice in mp3 format. Here the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468240/how-to-convert-g729-encoded-byte-array-to-wav-in-c).