# How to convert g729 encoded byte array to .WAV in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, converters, wav, codec

I have been working on a VoIP Application in C sharp language. The purpose of the project is VoIP Call Recording. It uses g729 Codec. I can extract the voice part from RTP payload. How to convert this Byte array to .wav format? Please help me.

Comment: I got the solution.Now i can play the captured voice calls.I used FFmpeg application.I can convert the saved rtp raw file with the help of FFmpeg tool.The following command is used for converting this "FFmpeg.exe -f g729 -i in.raw out.wav". After running the command we can get a wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [ffmpeg.exe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and work with it via command line